# What happened that makes my keyboard just a bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

For some reason that I don't know and can't find, my Keyboard, is just a bar.
I got several fields that needs a numeriek keyboard pad on the iPad/Ios.
It did work, but then i did dismiss the keyboard and it never comes back, not even after a restart of the simulator. Even when I set the keyboard type in IB, I got the same result, just a bar.

```
    self.NearPoint.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    self.FarPoint.keyboardType = .decimalPad
```

[the bar instead of the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9QkM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable/disable simulator keyboard,

⌘ + K (Ctrl + k)

To disable input from your keyboard,

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

Comment: Yes, so far so good. Never read anything about this ( I should read more ;) ). Never happende before too during dev. I thought a restart will do, but apparently not. Thank you Julian. Not enough point to add a vote yet.